# getting java NullPointerException in selenium code

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, frameworks

I have stuck in the selenium code i have developed a frame work of page_object model while running the code with the help of junit i am not able to run the selenium test it is throwing exception error as java Nullpointerexception.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/90C22.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/o46cT.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9Pqn.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You should post snippets of code inside your questions, but outside of that; in your `BaseClass.java` on line 27, you should try change the line to:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Don't use`WebDriver` in front, otherwise you would create a new object in memory instead of referring to the `driver` on line 18.

Comment: i have tried your suggestion or advise but i am getting same null pointer exception after running the script.